# What maintains constant voltage in a battery?

Tags: potential, potential-energy, voltage, batteries, chemical-potential

I know there's lots of questions that address similar situations, ([Batteries connected in Parallel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92144/batteries-connected-in-parallel),
[Batteries and fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107661/batteries-and-fields),
[Naive Question About Batteries](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31923/naive-question-about-batteries), 
and the oft-viewed
 [I don't understand what we really mean by voltage drop](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55948/i-dont-understand-what-we-really-mean-by-voltage-drop)).

However, I have a question, and after examining just the battery structure, I have been wondering, exactly what structure/process maintains the constant voltage drop within batteries? I mean, certain chemical reactions are occurring in each half-cell, and electrolytes maintain charge conservation, I get that there's some motivation for the electron to move from one cell to the other.

But why is this motivation so constant? I really want to get this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider for a moment, a cell that is not connected to a circuit, i.e., there is no path for current external to the cell.

The chemical reactions inside the cell remove electrons from the cathode and add electrons to the anode.

Thus, as the chemical reactions proceed, an electric field builds between the anode and cathode due to the differing charge densities.

It turns out that this electric field acts to *reduce* the rate of the chemical reactions within the cell.

At some point, the electric field is strong enough to effectively *stop* the chemical reactions within the cell.

The voltage across the terminals of the cell, due to this electric field, is then constant and this is the *open-circuit voltage* of the cell.

If an external circuit is connected to the cell, electrons flow from the anode through the external circuit and into the cathode, reducing the difference in charge densities which in turn reduces the electric field *just enough* such that the chemical reactions can once again take place to maintain the electric current through the circuit.

The larger the external current, the greater the required rate of chemical reactions and thus, the lower the voltage across the terminals.

As long as the circuit current is significantly less than the maximum current the chemicals reactions can sustain, the voltage across the battery terminals will be close to the open circuit voltage.

As the external current approaches the maximum current, the voltage across the terminals rapidly falls and when the voltage is zero, the cell is supplying maximum current.  This current is called the *short-circuit current*.

Comment: +1, and I'd add that the electric field required to stop the chemical reaction is related to the [redox potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_potential).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the above example, are the two electrodes connected by a salt bridge? Also, I thought that what slowed down the reaction was the electric field between the interior of the electrode and the electrolytic solution, not the electric field between the anode and cathode.

Comment: Also, I see that an electron going from point a (on an anode) to point b (on a cathode) will receive a given amount of energy and thus has a voltage, but what about a roundabout journey from a to b following a circuit? Is potential still the same in this case?

Comment: @AndresSalas, the example is general.  I don't quite understand what you mean by "interior of the electrode and the electrolytic solution".  Also, your 2nd comment is unclear.  We measure voltage *across* or *between* two points in a circuit.  I'm not quite sure how to interpret "an electron ... thus has a voltage".  Try this link:  http://www.av8n.com/physics/lead-acid.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. So, I know that the potential energy difference between electrodes has a cetain fixed quantity for the gap between the electrodes, why however is this potential energy difference the same if the bridge between the gap no longer is a straight line ie a circuit? I know no intuitive answer to this.

Comment: @AndresSalas, your intuition needs work is all.  Intuition is not automatic.  Intuition comes from studying and working with the subject, correcting erroneous premises and intuition along the way.  If you keep studying and asking questions, at some point you'll see where you're misconceptions are and, after correcting those, this *will* be intuitive.

Comment: I was just thinking about how all this works in terms of the process of learning. Physics is significantly dissimilar to mathematics in terms of reasoning in that assumptions are agreed upon in math. I'm basically always right in math, and always wrong in physics. Its very unclear and involves wrestling it seems @AlfredCentauri

Comment: +1 very helpful answer. I've always been scared of electrochemistry because I never could answer this kind of question to my own satisfaction.